# COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../API.Common.AspNetCore/API.Common.AspNetCore.csproj ()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution which contains multiple projects. I want to create a docker image of a project so I have added a Dockerfile via docker support. The project I have added the Dockerfile to has build dependencies on other projects at the same level. When I try to run the project via Docker I get the following error:

> COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../API.Common.AspNetCore/API.Common.AspNetCore.csproj ()
>
> C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.4.10\build\Container.targets(258,5): error CTP1001: An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API.Customer/API.Customer.csproj", "API.Customer/"]
COPY ["../API.Common.AspNetCore/API.Common.AspNetCore.csproj", "../API.Common.AspNetCore/"]
COPY ["API.Customer.Eventing/API.Customer.Eventing.csproj", "API.Customer.Eventing/"]
COPY ["API.Customer.Errors.Database.AspNetCore/API.Customer.Errors.Database.AspNetCore.csproj", "API.Customer.Errors.Database.AspNetCore/"]
COPY ["API.Customer.Errors.AspNetCore/API.Customer.Errors.AspNetCore.csproj", "API.Customer.Errors.AspNetCore/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API.Customer/API.Customer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API.Customer"
RUN dotnet build "API.Customer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API.Customer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.Customer.dll"]
```

**LaunchSettings.json:**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5002",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Dev"
      }
    },
    "STARS.API.Customer.Schools": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Dev"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5002"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}"
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you require more information.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to copy the `API.Common.AspNetCore` project into the directory above your work directory (`../`). That's not possible. I understand you're doing this because you need to maintain the relative project path references, but the only way to do that would be to embed the other projects one more directory deep. For example, instead of copying `API.Customer.csproj` to `API.Customer/`, copy to `foo/API.Customer/`. Then, for your `API.Common.AspNetCore` project, you can copy to just `API.Common.AspNetCore/`.

**EDIT**

Thinking about this more, the error is likely due to the opposite side of the equation, but the part above is also relevant. In short, Docker has a concept of a working or build directory, which is contextual to the directory that the Docker command is being run from. If you're running linux containers on Windows, then this becomes even more interesting, as that entire working directory is actually copied into the MobyLinux VM running in Hyper-V.

Anyways, because of this, you need to be careful about where you're running the Docker commands. If you need the context of a parent directory, then you need t to run out of that parent directory, so you have access to it and of course your project under it. Ironically, this is not something you have to really think about for a single Dockerfile, since traditionally, you don't have other participating applications when you're working with a Dockerfile directly. Conversely, when you are orchestrating multiple Docker apps, you'd traditionally be using a `docker-compose.yml` file, which would be at the parent level to all the participating apps. In either case, running those files directly in the folders they exist in would provide all the necessary context.

Your issue is that your effectively skating the two concepts, so you need to be much more careful about what your actual context is when you run your Docker commands. If you do have a docker-compose.yml, I'd recommend running that instead of the Dockerfile(s) directly. In Visual Studio, you simply need to add orchestration support, rather than adding Dockerfiles directly. This will add the Dockerfile, but *also* add a docker-compose project, and then it will up the docker-compose.yml, instead of building each image directly using the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2):

As @Chris Pratt says, if you have multiple projects in the solution it is best to use the file docker-compose.yml. But if for some reason you need to directly use Dokerfile and specify the context, you can add the following line to your ***.csproj** file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <DockerfileContext>../..</DockerfileContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For example, `../..` to go back once. Check [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/397004/docker-tools-docker-build-context-when-publishing.html).